# Google Apps Script: take some rows or submatrix in a matrix?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple question:

If i take a range of values in google apps script:

```
//For Example
  var matrix=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:D4").getValues();
```

matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]];

Is it possible to get some rows or submatrix like in Matlab Notation? Something like this:

```
var submatrix= matrix[1:3]; //to take last three rows: submatrix = [[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]];
// or
var submatrix= matrix[1:2][1:2]; //to take: submatrix = [[6,7],[10,11]];`
```

I can't find a similar notation. It's frustrating to use concat and similar functions or acting previously on the range. Do you know a simplier way to work with matrix and submatix quickly?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following sample script?

#### Pattern 1:

Use `slice`.

```js
var matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]];

var submatrix1 = matrix.slice(1, 4);
console.log(submatrix1) // [ [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ], [ 13, 14, 15, 16 ] ]

var submatrix2 = matrix.slice(1, 3).map(e => e.slice(1, 3));
console.log(submatrix2) // [ [ 6, 7 ], [ 10, 11 ] ]
```

- In this case, `matrix` is non-destructive.

#### Pattern 2:

Use `splice`.

```js
var matrix1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]];
var submatrix1 = matrix1.splice(1, 3);
console.log(submatrix1) // [ [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ], [ 13, 14, 15, 16 ] ]

var matrix2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]];
var submatrix2 = matrix2.splice(1, 2).map(e => e.splice(1, 2));
console.log(submatrix2) // [ [ 6, 7 ], [ 10, 11 ] ]
```

- In this case, `matrix` is destructive.
- In this case, at Google Apps Script, when the array length of `matrix` is large, when `splice` is used, the memory can be efficiently used than that of `slice`.

#### References:

- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what suits better for my case